# Tomcat java application background processing

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, cronexpression

I have a Tomcat application that needs to do various background housekeeping tasks.

e.g. User updates something and it make an entry in an event queue table. Then the background task reads the queue and sends an email. I need the table anyway as I will use it as an event log in the UI.

In the past I just used cron to schedule them from the command line. But I thought this time I should spend a few minutes and look for a better way...

Ideally, I would have some task idling in the application background. It would watch an application scope variable to trigger some activity.

I don't this it's complex enough to implement another framework. Just looking for a flag and trigger of some kind.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Actually in our project we implement a similar thing and we use spring-cron expression. I also watch the issue, is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

[Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org) is easy to use and will enable you to achieve this from within your application.